# HTTP Post to Server Device (Arduino) in local network with Android > 10 via flutter / dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, http, webserver

we are struggeling with the implementation of a http post to a device in the local network. We have an ESP8266 Board that is opening a webserver.

With cURL and via Browser everything works fine. In the following i'm showing the code of the successful cURL commands:

```
curl -d '{"displayoff":"","displayon":"","ssid":"examplessid","password":"examplepassword" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "192.168.10.2/save"

curl -d "displayoff=&displayon=&ssid=examplessid&password=examplepassword" -X POST "192.168.10.2/save"
```

When it now comes to Flutter, we were able to implement the http post in the android app for android version 8 and it works flawlessy. We connect to the Hotspot / Webserver that is opened by the ESP8266 and then we send the HTTP Post.

added to **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

**Dart code**:

```
Future<bool> postHttpData() async {
    bool retVal = false;
    var url = Uri.parse('http://192.168.10.2/save');
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
    var data =
        'displayoff=$nightStart&displayon=$nightEnd&ssid=$ssid&password=$password';
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('POSTING\r\n'
          '$url\r\n'
          '$headers\r\n'
          '$data');
    }

    // HTTP POST 
    Response? response;
    var dio = Dio();
    dio.options.contentType = Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType;
    dio.options.connectTimeout = 3000;
    dio.options.receiveTimeout = 3000;
    dio.options.followRedirects = false;
    dio.options.validateStatus = (status) {
      return status! < 500;
    };

    try {
      response = await dio.post('http://192.168.10.2/save', data: data);
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('POSTED');
      }
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 303) {
        retVal = true;
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Sent http post with:\r\nstatusCode= ${response.statusCode}\r\n'
              'Sent off = $nightStart\r\n'
              'Sent on = $nightEnd\r\n'
              'Sent ssid = $ssid\r\n'
              'Sent password = $password'
              'Response body = ${response.data}');
        }
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(
              'Failed sending http post!\r\nstatusCode= ${response.statusCode}\r\n'
              'Sent off = $nightStart\r\n'
              'Sent on = $nightEnd\r\n'
              'Sent ssid = $ssid\r\n'
              'Sent password = $password'
              'Response body = ${response.data}');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      print(
          'Exception on http post with:\r\nstatusCode= ${response?.statusCode}\r\n'
          'Sent off = $nightStart\r\n'
          'Sent on = $nightEnd\r\n'
          'Sent ssid = $ssid\r\n'
          'Sent password = $password'
          'Response body = ${response?.data}');
    }

    return retVal;
  }
}
```

When i try to execute this app on my Android 12 i'm getting an exception at the http post:

```
I/flutter (21121): POSTING
I/flutter (21121): http://192.168.10.2/save
I/flutter (21121): {Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded}
I/flutter (21121): displayoff=&displayon=&ssid=Tell my WiFi love her&password=Gohawks#19
I/flutter (21121): DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 192.168.10.2, port = 57012
I/flutter (21121): Source stack:
I/flutter (21121): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35)
I/flutter (21121): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12)
I/flutter (21121): #2      DioMixin.post (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:97:12)
I/flutter (21121): #3      WordClockHttp.postHttpData (package:word_clock/wifi/word_clock.dart:559:28)
I/flutter (21121): #4      WordClock.configWifiDataViaHttp (package:word_clock/wifi/word_clock.dart:169:29)
I/flutter (21121): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (21121): #5      _ConfigState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:word_clock/view_wifi_config.dart:189:21)
I/flutter (21121): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (21121): Exception on http post with:
I/flutter (21121): statusCode= null
I/flutter (21121): Sent off = 
I/flutter (21121): Sent on =
```

There are a lot of threads with the issue "OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111" but even with all these threads i couldn't get the code work.

I think the issue is, that we are trying to http post clear data without encryption to a HTTP and not HTTPS.

Does someone have an idea how to fix that?

Thank you so much and best regards
Meister Tubi

Comment: What does 111 mean?

Comment: I think that's the error number, i don't know. That's the exception output of the http post lib, am i right?

Comment: Yes, i referred to that errno number. And i asked what it means. Please find out as it will tell you the cause of connection refuse.

Comment: It seems to indicate that the connection to the socket failed only. No more information. There can be many reasons, that the connection was not successful. 
But thank you for the hint!

Comment: Again: find out what 111 means!!! Not many reasons behind 111!! Only one! Find out! Ask the developers.

Comment: The connection did not fail at first. There was a connection. But then it was refused. Hmmm... or it was refused before there was a connection. Find out what really happens and who produces the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the HTTP Post works perfectly, when i connect to the HotSpot of my ESP8266 manually in Android 12. But when i connect via App, the HTTP Post is not working anymore.

The only differences i found are the following:
When i connect manually to the Hotspot, my phone shows "connected without internet", but when i connect via App it shows "connected over 'NameOfApp'".
When i close my app, the WiFi connection to the hotspot is disconnected.

So in my thoughts, the WiFi connection established by the app has another behavior (restrictions, security, ...). This results in not working http posts.

Does anyone have a clue to get this work? I found NOTHING in the internet about this App WiFi connection...